# how to select PostgreSQL jsonb items?

Tags: php, postgresql, jsonb

I have a JSONB value that's

```json
table={
       "id": 1,
       "items": [
         {
           "model": 1
         },
         {
           "model": 2
         }
       ]
      }
```

how to select multiple items from that?

I've already tried

```
table[0]['items'][0];
```

but this selected only one object.

Comment: It's an object at the top level, not an array. So just `table["items"][0]`, I'd expect. Make sure you understand the difference between `{` and `[` in JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Try next:

```
SELECT '{"id":1,"items":[{"model":1},{"model":2}]}'::jsonb->'items'->0;
```

[Test here](https://sqlize.online/sql/psql14/9144ff652cf89e79d3643df6e36f35bc/)